# How to get the all post from two custom post types?

Tags: wordpress

How to get the all post from two custom post types (team, work) using `WP_Query`?

This is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'post_per_page'=>-1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of allowed types:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'team', 'work' ), // Specify your types here
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // Fixed typo here refer to postS
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The full [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) includes more examples on how to use `WP_Query`.

Comment: Getting only 5 posts i want to display all posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your query here.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'team','work' ),
    'post_per_page'=>-1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and for more future reference check this post

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'team', 'work'), // Specify your custom post types slug here"
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
    'caller_get_posts' => -1
);
$query = null;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```